# Defining function signatures for specific parameter values - argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to specify specific return types based on the values of properties passed to a method.

This works with a single signature, however fails when I try to define different overloads restricted on parameter values.

```
class Cat{}
class Dog{}
type MyType = {
    // This works
    //call: ((method: 'cat') => Cat) 

    // this errors
     call: ((method: 'cat') => Cat) | ((method: 'dog') => Dog) 
};

var s:MyType = {
  call(method:string): Cat | Dog
  {
    return new Cat()
  }
}

// err: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
let result = s.call('cat');
```

Is it possible to achieve what I'm after?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your variance backward.

```
call: ((method: 'cat') => Cat) | ((method: 'dog') => Dog)
```

This says "`call` is either a function that takes the string `'cat'` or a function that takes the string `'dog'`". There's no way to know *which* type of function it is, so we can never call it. Typescript performed the following simplifications.

```
((method: 'cat') => Cat) | ((method: 'dog') => Dog)
((method: 'cat') => Cat | Dog) | ((method: 'dog') => Cat | Dog)
(method: 'cat' & 'dog') => Cat | Dog
(method: never) => Cat | Dog
```

The first simplification is by covariance of return type. A function that returns `Cat` can be said to return a supertype (`Cat | Dog`), and the same of a function which returns `Dog`. Then we have distributivity of arguments. If we have a value of type `((A) => R) | ((B) => R)`, then that value can only be called with an argument that is *both* an `A` and a `B`, hence what we really have is `(A & B) => R`. Finally, `'cat' & 'dog'` is `never` since there are no strings that are equal to both `'cat`' and `'dog'` simultaneously.

Consider using an intersection instead.

```
call: ((method: 'cat') => Cat) & ((method: 'dog') => Dog)
```

This way, `call` is a function which can be called in one of two ways, and each way will produce a different return type. Typescript performs similar simplifications.

```
((method: 'cat') => Cat) & ((method: 'dog') => Dog)
((method: 'cat') => Cat | Dog) & ((method: 'dog') => Cat | Dog)
(method: 'cat' | 'dog') => Cat | Dog
```

The first simplification is the same. The second changes our intersection `&` to a union `|` (since argument types are contravariant), so the thing we end up with is a function that takes *either* `'cat'` or `'dog'` and produces something that is either a `Cat` or a `Dog`.